# Making a shopping cart in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, shopping-cart

I am learning Python, and I'm am trying to make a shopping cart (for practice). But I got kinda stuck here:

```
# Vars
budget = 200; # Budget
total = 0; # Total price
prices = { # Price list
    "cola":22,
    "chips":18,
    "headset":800,
    "pencil":5
}
cart = [] # Shopping cart

while True:
    cmd = raw_input("Enter command: ");
    if cmd == "additem":
```

In the while loop (specifically the "if cmd == "additem") I want the user to enter the name of an item (from the prices dictionary) and then it adds it to the cart. However, I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me :) , Where are you stuck exactly? Do you not know how to get the input from the user? Are you looking to do this from the command line, through the shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homework?

Your data structures are a little odd. You probably want the cart to be a list of tuples or something, with each tuple being item, quantity, or even item, quantity, subtotal. However.

```
if cmd == "additem":
    item = raw_input("Enter item name: ")
    cart.append(item)

#at the end
for item in cart:
    print "Item: %s. Price: %s" % (item, prices[item])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Vars
budget = 200; # Budget
total = 0; # Total price
prices = { # Price list
    "cola":22,
    "chips":18,
    "headset":800,
    "pencil":5
}
cart = [] # Shopping cart

input = ['']
while input[0] != 'quit':
    input = raw_input("Enter command: ").split()
    if input[0] == 'additem' and input[1] in prices:
        cart.append(input[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Vars
budget = 200; # Budget
total = 0; # Total price
prices = { # Price list
    "cola":22,
    "chips":18,
    "headset":800,
    "pencil":5
}
cart = [] # Shopping cart
cmd = raw_input("""
====Item=====Price====

    cola    :  22 $
    chips   :  18 $
    headset : 800 $
    pencil  :   5 $

Enter order:""")
while cmd in prices.keys():
    cart+=[(cmd,prices[cmd])]
    cmd = raw_input("Enter order: ")

if cmd not in ["","\t","\n"]:
    print cmd," is not available",

print"you cart contains :\n"
if cart != []:
    for item in cart:
        print item[0],"\t:",item[1]," $"
else:
    print "Nothing"

raw_input("\nPress enter to exit...")
```